# auto update values in connected sheets using Excel IF function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a connection between two sheets using this formula
 `=IF(parent!A1=0,"",child!A1)`
which inserts an empty string instead of a 0

inserting a row between the existing values does not auto update the value in the child sheet, I need to manually pull the function over all values in the second sheet

reading the docs [INDIRECT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) is recommended
after trying to implement the function I got a `#REF!`

`=IF(INDIRECT(parent!A1)=0,"",INDIRECT(child!A1))`

How can I get the desired behavior of auto updating ?

parent

| left |
| --- |
| foo |
| bar |
| bazz |

child

| left |
| --- |
| foo |
| bar |
| bazz |

Comment: You can try `=IF(parent!A1=0,"",Index(child!A:A,row()))`

Comment: this works, but it automatically insert a 0 value on insert which Im trying to prevent

Comment: You can use formatting to hide zero. Try this cell formatting `0;-0;;@,`. [Microsoft article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/display-or-hide-zero-values-3ec7a433-46b8-4516-8085-a00e9e476b03)

Comment: problem is that the depending formula can not except 0 values

Comment: Are you saying the problem is that after inserting a row in the parent sheet, your formula becomes e.g. `=IF(parent!A3=0,"",child!A2)` and that you want the formula to update with `child!A3` to match the parent reference ?

Comment: correct If I insert a row between the values in the parent sheet the value gets not updated   to the child sheet, insert a value at the end of all values works, also updating an existing value

Answer (score 0):

[ Use indirect with IF ]

Put in all the cell in child sheet :
`=IF(OFFSET(INDIRECT("parent!A1"),ROW()-1,COLUMN()-1)="","",OFFSET(INDIRECT("parent!A1"),ROW()-1,COLUMN()-1))`

Idea : `IF` force "" if there is no value in parent sheet. `Indirect` with `row()` & `column()` make the `child` Sheet formula refer to `parent` sheet via relative location of the current cell. This type of link follow the insert/delete column/row changes in the `parent` sheet.